# How to solve this linear system using determinants and using matrices

Tags: algebra-precalculus

$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
2x + y + 3z = 1 \\
5x + z = 3y - 3 \\
2y + z = 4 \\
\end{array}\right.$$

Here is my problem. I know how to calculate it using matrices, but i don't know how to organize it, the thing it confuses me is the second equation and the 'y' after the equal sign.

Comment: Move the $3y$ to the LHS in that equation... and be happy!

Comment: Rewrite the second equation as $5x-3y+z=-3$

Answer (score 1):

Please *do* brush up on your MathJax/LaTeX, because the problem was next to unreadable. I was close to interpreting it as a chain of equalities (i.e. $2x+y+3z=13x-3y+z=-32y+z=4$) instead of the linear system it was. Anyway the problem is equivalent to:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{c}
2x+y+3z=1 \\
5x-3y+z=-3 \\
2y+z=4
\end{array}\right.$$
as obtained by transporting all variables to left-hand sides. In terms of matrices, this can be written as:
$$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2 & 1 & 3 \\
5 & -3 & 1 \\
0 & 2 & 1
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}
x \\
y \\
z \\
\end{array}\right)=\left(\begin{array}{c}
1 \\
-3 \\
4
\end{array}\right),$$
and I take it you can handle it yourself from here.

Comment: Should the coefficient of $x$ in the second equation be $5$ (as in the question) or $3$ (as in your answer)?

Comment: Must have mistyped :). Fixed.